# Recursive function for combinations

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to solve the following problem :

> Given two integers n and k, return all possible combinations of k
>   numbers out of 1 ... n.

I'm doing it in ruby and tried to implement this solution https://gist.github.com/safeng/8156755, but my result is always *empty*.

```
def combine(n, k)
    res = [[]]

    return res if k > n || n == 0

    sol = []
    comb(0, 0, k, n, sol, res)
    res
end

def comb(start, idx, k, n, sol, res)
  if idx == k
     res << sol
  else
    (start..n).to_a.each do |i|
      sol << (i + 1)
      comb(i + 1, idx + 1, k, n, sol, res)
      sol.pop
    end
  end
end

print combine(4, 2) #[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you

**NOTE (UPDATED):**

Code that works:

```
def combine(n, k)
    res = []

    return res if k > n || n == 0

    sol = []
    comb(0, 0, k, n, sol, res)
    res
end

def comb(start, idx, k, n, sol, res)
  if idx == k
     res << sol.dup
  else
    (start..n - 1).to_a.each do |i|
      sol << (i + 1)
      comb(i + 1, idx + 1, k, n, sol, res)
      sol.pop
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few bugs in your code:

You don't need to add an empty array to res when you initialize it in `combine`:

```
res = []
```

When you add the `sol` to `res` you should duplicate it rather than pushing a reference, otherwise the solutions that you have already added to `res` will get modified when you modify `sol`:

```
if idx == k
    res << sol.dup
```

Lastly, you only need to loop to `n-1` (because you are pushing `i + 1` to `sol`):

```
(start..n-1).to_a.each do |i|
```